# How can I remove the number from file name?

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-xd, bigdata

I use Spring XD and I have created the following stream:

```
stream create --name test --definition "time | hdfs --rollover=1B --directory=/xd/test --fileName=test --overwrite=true" --deploy
```

The stream generate a many file. Each file name contains the name and additional number e.g. test-0.txt, test-1.txt, test-2.txt etc.

Because I use Spring XD and Hadoop for educational purpose I want to save free space of my hard drive. So, I would like to overwrite the data. It is possible to remove the above number from file name?

Answer (score 0):

The rollover size 1B is too small which pile up the number of files being created. You can set to use optimal size based on the data you process to control the number of files created.

For more number of options to control the properties you can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#hadoop-hdfs)